# Как убрать none?

Tags: python

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно убрать None в конце?

```
def prime_eratosthenes(n):
prime_list = []
for i in range(2, n+1):
    if i not in prime_list:
        print (i)
        for j in range(i*i, n+1, i):
            prime_list.append(j)

print(prime_eratosthenes(5))
```

Вывод:

```
2
3
5
None
```

Comment: Уберите print в конце.

prime_eratosthenes(5)

Comment: Не очень ваш алгоритм похож на решето Эратосфена. Там же вроде не список используется, а выделяется битовый массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае внутри цикла вызывается вывод значений через `print(i)`. А в конце добавляется `None` - это возвращаемое значение ваше функцией. Она ничего не возвращает, поэтому её не нужно помещать в `print()`, её следует просто вызвать.

Следовательно, последнюю строчку следует заменить на простой вызов без `print()`

`prime_eratosthenes(5)`

Comment: мой ответ с дополнениями))

Comment: Я увидел твой после того, как ответил. И дело в том, что мы решали одну и и ту же проблему, а не в том, чей это ответ. Мы просто оба дали верный ответ.

Comment: Да я и не ругаюсь)))

Comment: ........Лады =))

Answer (score 3):

Решение простое:

- Замените `print(prime_eratosthenes(5))` на `prime_eratosthenes(5)`.

Если вы не используете `return`, зачем использовать `print(функция)`?!